# Can Visual Studio 2015 compile C++ libs to Android/iOS?

Tags: android, c++, ios, visual-studio

So I have a project that consists of a couple C++ libraries and a bunch of header files. Can Visual Studio 2015 compile all those to Android/iOS?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/android/

Comment: @S.M. I am talking about compiling

Comment: Have you the source of the libraries or are they external libraries without source? In the first case you can compile for Android and also use Xamarin, in the second case no.